# How to show that $(n\mathbb Z+a)(n\mathbb Z+b) = n\mathbb Z + (ab)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations, integers

I am studying the equivalence classes of the relation congruence $\operatorname{mod}n$ on $\mathbb Z$. I define for any $A, B\subseteq\mathbb Z$,
\begin{align*}
A+B & := \{a+b : a\in A, b\in B\}\text{, and}\tag{1}\\
AB  & := \{ab : a\in A, b\in B\}\text{.}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

With these definitions in hand, I can show that$^1$
$$
(n\mathbb Z + a) + (n\mathbb Z+b) = n\mathbb Z+(a+b)\text{.}\tag{a}
$$

But I am struggling to show that
$$
(n\mathbb Z+a)(n\mathbb Z+b) = n\mathbb Z + (ab)\text{.}\tag{b}
$$

I have figured out that I will be done if I can prove that for an $n, a, b, k\in\mathbb Z$, there exist $k_1, k_2$ such that $k = nk_1 k_2 + k_1 a + k_2 b$. But I am stuck here. Induction doesn't seem to help.

**Questions:**

1. Can someone help with the proof of $(\text{b})$? (I can show that the LHS is a subset of the RHS, not the other way around.) Or give a counterexample?
2. If it is false in general, is there any other definition of $AB$ so that the result follows? Or should I really just take $(\text{a})$ and $(\text{b})$ as my (less general) definitions?

---

$^1$ $n\mathbb Z+a :=\{nk+a : k\in\mathbb Z\}$. It is easily shown that $n\mathbb Z+a$ is the equivalence class (also called congruence class) containing $a$.

---

Thanks to [Conifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/152568/conifold) for his comment. According to definition $(2)$, I'll have $(2\mathbb Z)(2\mathbb Z) = 4\mathbb Z$, whereas we want the RHS to be $2\mathbb Z$ according to $(\text{b})$. Hence, $(2)$ and $(\text{b})$ are not compatible.

Further, see his comments on how to define $AB$ *when $A$, $B$ are equivalence classes*.

Comment: Hint: $(a+nk_1)(b+nk_2) = ab+n( ak_2+ bk_1+nk_1k_2)$.

Comment: @Conifold That just helps to show that LHS of $(\text{b})$ is a subset of the RHS. I am stuck of the other sided inclusion. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Take $a=b=n=2$ and $k=1$. Then your equation becomes $1 = 2k_1 k_2 + 2k_1 + 2k_2$, and no integers satisfy it. To show that multiplication of equivalence classes is well-defined you do not need to show that every representative of the product class must be a product of representatives of classes that it is the product of.

Comment: @Conifold So you are suggesting to take $(\text{a})$ and $(\text{b})$ as the definitions instead?

Comment: No, take the standard definition. If $A$, $B$ are equivalence classes and $a\in A$, $b\in B$ than $AB:=(ab)$, the equivalence class of $ab$. You have to show that this is well-defined, i.e. if $a'\in A$, $b'\in B$ are some other representatives then $(ab)=(a'b')$. But that follows from the hint in the first comment. In general, $AB$ so defined is strictly larger than the set product of $A$ and $B$ defined in $(2)$.

Comment: @Conifold Oh, okay. Now I got it. Thanks a lot.